# Data Grid Row selection/Focus from View Model

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am working on a WPF application.  As per requirement I have a dynamic data grid (User can select the columns to display) in my main page.  Currently I am using  MVVM design pattern.
One of the column in my data grid is “Line Number”(1,2,3,…250) . 
As per new requirement I need to add a text box in this main screen. Once the user enter the line number in this test box and clicking “ENTER” key I need to select/Focus  the corresponding line in the datagrid. 
How can I implement this from Vie Model?

1. How can I select a data grid Row from the  View Model.?
2. How can I move the scroll position to that particular data row?

Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: by dynamic you mean you create your DataGrid in code or only your ItemsSource?

Answer (score 1):

First, each item of the collection should have a Boolean property to indicate whether it's selected (let's call it `Selected`). Then in data grid:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
             <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </Style>
    <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
 ........
 </DataGrid>
```

[of course all properties should have change notification]

About scrolling, I'd go with a [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946954/make-listview-scrollintoview-scroll-the-item-into-the-center-of-the-listview-c), the question is targeting `ListBox` but the answer is for `ItemsControl` in general, so it should work for `DataGrid`.

So, when the user enters line number, you find the relevant item, set it's `Selected` property to `true` and everything else should be taken care of.