# TreeView Highlighted node Bring to Center

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a 5 level TreeView in WPF. I am making a find function in which child matching some specific condition will be highlighted in yellow border as below:
[image]

Now i am using **BringIntoView()** to expand and show that item on screen but it is remaining at bottom of screen but i **want it in center/middle** of the screen.

Code which I am using is this:

```
  private TreeViewItem GetTreeViewItem(ItemsControl container, object item)
        {
            if (container != null)
            {
                if (container.DataContext == item)
                {
                    return container as TreeViewItem;
                }

                // Expand the current container
                if (container is TreeViewItem && !((TreeViewItem)container).IsExpanded)
                {
                    container.SetValue(TreeViewItem.IsExpandedProperty, true);
                }

                // Try to generate the ItemsPresenter and the ItemsPanel.
                // by calling ApplyTemplate.  Note that in the 
                // virtualizing case even if the item is marked 
                // expanded we still need to do this step in order to 
                // regenerate the visuals because they may have been virtualized away.

                container.ApplyTemplate();
                ItemsPresenter itemsPresenter =
                    (ItemsPresenter)container.Template.FindName("ItemsHost", container);
                if (itemsPresenter != null)
                {
                    itemsPresenter.ApplyTemplate();
                }
                else
                {
                    // The Tree template has not named the ItemsPresenter, 
                    // so walk the descendents and find the child.
                    itemsPresenter = FindVisualChild<ItemsPresenter>(container);
                    if (itemsPresenter == null)
                    {
                        container.UpdateLayout();

                        itemsPresenter = FindVisualChild<ItemsPresenter>(container);
                    }
                }

                Panel itemsHostPanel = (Panel)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(itemsPresenter, 0);


                // Ensure that the generator for this panel has been created.
                UIElementCollection children = itemsHostPanel.Children;

                TestDataVirtualizingStackPanel virtualizingPanel =
                    itemsHostPanel as TestDataVirtualizingStackPanel;

                for (int i = 0, count = container.Items.Count; i < count; i++)
                {
                    TreeViewItem subContainer;
                    if (virtualizingPanel != null)
                    {
                        // Bring the item into view so 
                        // that the container will be generated.
                        virtualizingPanel.BringIntoView(i);

                        subContainer =
                            (TreeViewItem)container.ItemContainerGenerator.
                            ContainerFromIndex(i);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        subContainer =
                            (TreeViewItem)container.ItemContainerGenerator.
                            ContainerFromIndex(i);

                        // Bring the item into view to maintain the 
                        // same behavior as with a virtualizing panel.
                        subContainer.BringIntoView();
                    }

                    if (subContainer != null)
                    {
                        // Search the next level for the object.
                        TreeViewItem resultContainer = GetTreeViewItem(subContainer, item);
                        if (resultContainer != null)
                        {
                            return resultContainer;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // The object is not under this TreeViewItem
                            // so collapse it.
                            subContainer.IsExpanded = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Does somebody have an idea that how can i bring that highlighted node into middle?

Comment: What if you have several nodes matching search condition?

Comment: [make-listview-scrollintoview-scroll-the-item-into-the-center-of-the-listview-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946954/make-listview-scrollintoview-scroll-the-item-into-the-center-of-the-listview-c)

Comment: [centering-selected-item-in-a-scroll-viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595675/centering-selected-item-in-a-scroll-viewer)

Comment: @Rekshino I will not have everal nodes matching search condition because i will only highlight next matching condition node.