# Binding a control through CommandParameter in MenuItem

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have been trying to implement a "jump to" menu as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26240221/jump-to-navigation-inside-a-usercontrol). As long as I did a binding inside a simple Button, everything was OK:

```
            <Button Foreground="Black" Style="{StaticResource MyButton}" 
                    Command="{StaticResource JumpToElementCommand}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=rect4}" 
                    Content="Go to rect4"/>
```

The problem showed up when I tried to use this method inside a MenuItem:

```
       <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Menu x:Name="myJumpMenu" Style="{StaticResource MyMenu}" 
                  Grid.Column="1">
                <MenuItem Name="jumpToRectItem"
                  Command="{StaticResource JumpToElementCommand}"
                  Style="{StaticResource MyMenuItemStyle}">
                    <MenuItem.CommandParameter>
                        <Binding ElementName="rect4"/>
                    </MenuItem.CommandParameter>
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
            <Rectangle Width="100" Height="700" 
                       Fill="Purple" Margin="10" x:Name="rect4"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

I have tried to cope with it with a solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013558/elementname-binding-from-menuitem-in-contextmenu) by putting a NameScope static method in code behind of UserControl in various places (in a constructor and in Loaded and Initialized events).

```
NameScope.SetNameScope(contextMenu, NameScope.GetNameScope(this));
```

Instead of getting a reference to the Rectangle, I get a null value. Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: In order for anyone to provide you with a valid `Binding path`, we'd need to know where `rect4` is declared in relation to the `Menu`... if you'd actually like an answer, perhaps you could enlighten us?

Comment: I doubt that there is some bug in `CommandParameter` Binding, sometimes the parameter is not actually passed and what we have is always null. So I prefer to using `CommandBinding` or just don't use `CommandParameter` at all.

Comment: I have edited the code. The `Rectangle` is in the same `StackPanel` as the `Menu`. Is it because the `MenuItem` is nested in `Menu` and that's why the name is not seen? How can I use `CommandBinding` to pass a reference to a control?