# scroll horizontal Listbox when selecting an item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

### Issue

---

I have a Horizontal Listbox that contains a List of images that a user can click on to select (*See Below*)

[image]

In this List are 21 images so it creates a scroll bar at the bottom. When selecting an image at the far right of the image above, I would like the scroll bar to move along so that the selected slide is now in the middle. (*See Below*)

[image]

I have tried to add a behaviour to my Listbox which does get hit on slide selection, but does not work.

```
<ListBox dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True" dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True" Background="#ececec" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSlideDataItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding SlideDataItems}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="10" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="13" MouseDoubleClick="ListBox_MouseDoubleClick">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:ListBoxSelectedItemsBehavior/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>



public class ListBoxSelectedItemsBehavior : Behavior<ListBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += AssociatedObjectSelectionChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= AssociatedObjectSelectionChanged;
    }

    void AssociatedObjectSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            // Assuming your selection mode is single.
            AssociatedObject.ScrollIntoView(e.AddedItems[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ScrollIntoView` doesn't do anything because it's already in the view. I see your intent is to avoid using scrollbar, so the the user can simply press the rightmost item and then it will be centered, so that user can continue selecting rightmost item to scroll to the right, right?

Comment: @Sinatr I still want to keep the scrollbar but just so that if you click the far right item it moves into centre :)

Comment: You'll probably need to do it manually: Handle the SelectionChanged, calculate the item position relative to the listbox and call the scrollviewer scrolltohorizontaloffset

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2946954/1997232).

Comment: @Sinatr I will take a look now.

Comment: @Sinatr This worked perfectly thanks.