# ScrollIntoView won't trigger after ShowDialog

Tags: .net, wpf, datagridview, datatable

The code is supposed to trigger once I'm done editing data in the secondary window. Everything works as it should, but the `ScrollIntoView` won't trigger. It selects the correct `Index`, but then refuses to scroll to it.

I'm completely lost at this point. I'm suspecting it has to do something with the fact that it takes about **500ms** to load the `DataTable` in the `DataGrid` (I'm playing with some weird queries) and the code tries to move to the `SelectedIndex` before it is even possible?

Note: "dg_part.SelectedIndex = -1;" has to be there, or I can't trigger a new SelectionChanged event correctly.

Code:

```
    public void DG_Part_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CurrentPartID != 0)
        {
            int lastId = CurrentPartID;
            EditWindow ew = new EditWindow(CurrentPartID)
            {
                Owner = this
            };
            ew.ShowDialog();
            if (Public_Strings.invokeDataGridParts == "yes")
            {
                InvokeDataGridPart();
                SqlPartsSetToRow(lastId);
                dg_part.ScrollIntoView(dg_part.Items[dg_part.SelectedIndex]);
                dg_part.SelectedIndex = -1;
            }
        }
    }

    public void InvokeDataGridPart()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
        {
            CommandText = "SELECT * FROM cbu_deli WHERE [IDX] = '" + CurrentID + "' ORDER BY LEN ([DEL]), [DEL] ASC, [OPIS] DESC, [DELEZ] DESC",
            Connection = con
        };
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Wait;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        dtPart.Clear();
        da.Fill(dtPart);
        dg_part.ItemsSource = dtPart.DefaultView;
        mycollection.GroupDescriptions.Clear();
        mycollection.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("DEL"));
        dg_part.ItemsSource = mycollection.View;
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Arrow;
    }

    public int CurrentPartID
    {
        get
        {
            int tmp = 0;
            if (dg_part.SelectedIndex >= 0)
            {
                int.TryParse(dtPart.Rows[dg_part.SelectedIndex].ItemArray[0].ToString(), out tmp);
            }
            return tmp;
        }
    }


    public void SqlPartsSetToRow(int Id)
    {
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Wait;
        dg_part.SelectionChanged -= DG_Part_SelectionChanged;
        while (CurrentPartID != Id && dg_part.SelectedIndex < dtPart.Rows.Count - 1)
        {
            dg_part.SelectedIndex++;
        }
        dg_part.SelectionChanged += DG_Part_SelectionChanged;
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Arrow;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've "solved" it by adding a 0 ms delay. Don't ask me why it works. If someone has an explanation, I'd appreciate it.

1. ```
   public DispatcherTimer Delay;

   public void DispatcherTimer()
   {
       Delay = new DispatcherTimer();
       Delay.Tick += DelayTick;
       Delay.Interval = new TimeSpan(0);
   }
   ```
2. ```
   public void DG_Part_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   {
       if (CurrentPartID != 0)
       {
           int lastId = CurrentPartID;
           EditWindow ew = new EditWindow(CurrentPartID)
           {
               Owner = this
           };
           ew.ShowDialog();
           if (Public_Strings.invokeDataGridParts == "yes")
           {
               InvokeDataGridPart();
               SqlPartsSetToRow(lastId);
               Delay.Start();
           }
       }
   }

   public void DelayTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Delay.Stop();
       dg_part.ScrollIntoView(dg_part.Items[dg_part.SelectedIndex]);
       dg_part.SelectedIndex = -1;
   }
   ```

**EDIT: The following solution solved my problem and added centering:**

(Be sure to change ScrollIntoView into ScrollToCenterOfView)

[Make ListView.ScrollIntoView Scroll the Item into the Center of the ListView (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946954/make-listview-scrollintoview-scroll-the-item-into-the-center-of-the-listview-c)

Had to modify a tiny part:

```
        // Compute the center point of the container relative to the scrollInfo
        System.Windows.Size size = container.RenderSize;
        System.Windows.Point center = container.TransformToAncestor((Visual)scrollInfo).Transform(new System.Windows.Point(size.Width / 2, size.Height / 2));
```